# Will unique_ptr take control of any pointer it is passed, regardless of how it was created?

Tags: c++

I have been doing this for my `std::vector` of `unique_ptr`s:

```
m_stuff.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Thing> (new DerivedThing()));
```

This gives me that automatic memory deletion when elements in the vector are removed.

I have another scenario whereby something else creates the heap memory via `new` and thus a generic pointer already exists. Now, suppose I do this:

```
    m_stuff.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Thing> (thingy));
    //thingy is Thing*
```

Can I safely assume that as soon as I do this, my vector `m_stuff` now has control over `thingy` such that when it is removed from the vector, it is `delete`d? Of course, there is the possibility of a dangling pointer if `thingy` was copied or stored elsewhere but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_ptr` has nothing magical in it. It has jus a regular constructor (actually it has a few) that takes a pointer of type `T` and becomes responsible for deleting the pointee. So yes, it does not care (and can't care) where did this pointer came from

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: You should store *any* pointer you create by allocating memory immediately into a smart pointer. Or put otherwise: (Almost) never use plain `new`, except in C++11 `unique_ptr` initialization. For `shared_ptr` there is `make_shared`, and in C++14 there will be `make_unique`.

Corollary: **Don't do this. `std::unique_ptr<Thing> (thingy)` is wrong**, either because you did not manage `thingy`'s memory in smart pointers from the beginning (then you should fix that), or because `thingy` does not own the object, i.e. it is just a plain referencing pointer and you are not allowed to steal someone elses ownership to pass it to the `unique_ptr`. You will get UB when both the `unique_ptr` and the real owner try to destroy the object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. Once constructed from a raw pointer, the unique pointer owns the pointee.